# Set focus on an EditorFor without the use of JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is it possible to set the focus on the following code on a page load without the use of JavaScript?

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
</div>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your can use the `autofocus` attribute. [Refer documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, new { autofocus = "autofocus" })
```

The equivalent for `EditorFor` (using MVC-5.1+ only) is obtained with the following syntax:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { autofocus = "autofocus" } })
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that.

Comment: Being fairly new to ASP.NET MVC, will it be a big deal switching from an EditorFor to a TextBoxFor?

Comment: Should work the same with EditorFor (the code was just cut and paste from my project - I changed the property name but didn't notice you used EditorFor). Also note docs - no support for older versions of IE

Comment: No, it does not work with Editor For, I had to change it to textboxfor

Comment: @RickerSilva - I added the syntax to use with `EditorFor`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, That is only applicable for MVC-5.1+ (not MVC -3 as tagged so I have edited again to be clear)

Answer (score 1):

You can add id to your div and pass this id int the end of the url of your page:

```
<div class="col-md-10" id="description">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
</div>

http://site/page#description
```