# How can I set focus on "FacultyName" textbox on page load for the following Razor code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Faculty Name *</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.FacultyName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Technician e.t.c", @name = "txtfacultyname" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.FacultyName, "", new { @class = "error" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label>EmailAddress *</label>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.EmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "abc@abc.com", @name = "txtemailaddress" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "error" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label>User Name *</label>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "abc e.t.c", @name = "txtusername" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.UserName, "", new { @class = "error" })
</div>
```

Comment: Refer [Set focus on an EditorFor without the use of JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934846/set-focus-on-an-editorfor-without-the-use-of-javascript/24935030#24935030)

Comment: And as a side note remove your pointless `new { @name = "xxx" }` Fortunately it does nothing at all (look at the html your generating), because it it did, model binding would fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#FacultyName').focus()`

I changed your code a bit just to show you that it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#FacultyName').focus() // This code will only run when the page is done loading/ready
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Faculty Name *</label>
  <input id="FacultyName"></input>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>EmailAddress *</label>
  <input id="EmailAddress"></input>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>User Name *</label>
  <input id="UserName"></input>
</div>
```