# jQuery focus on select box not working when getting element id from razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, focus

I am trying to highlight the first select box on the page load so that when user presses enter it will open the options or move to other select box when user presses tab. I am getting the element id in razor syntax, I tried writing the jQuery code like below but it is not working, I am not sure if any other code is overriding my focus function. Pls help

This is my Select box:

```
<div id="originalAmount_@differAmountId" class="divoriginalAmount">

    <select class="cs-select cs-skin-border billAccountAmount " data-label="@StringResource.Lbl_Pay " id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.AmountOptionList)">
```

This is my function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#@Html.IdFor(m => Model.AmountOptionList)').first().focus();
});
```

I have also tried with `.get(0).focus();` but that also did not help.

Comment: You use of `.first()` suggests you have multiple elements with that `id` which is invalid html

Comment: Note also you do not really need a script for this - you can just use the `autofocus` attribute (refer [Set focus on an EditorFor without the use of JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934846/set-focus-on-an-editorfor-without-the-use-of-javascript/24935030#24935030))

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am required to use jQuery for it. Also I checked , there are unique id's , using .first() was part of my trial and error.

Comment: The code you have shown works fine so there is something else you have not shown causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

instead of using id you can use class selector.

```
 $('.cs-select').first().focus();
```

Comment: I am required to use Id , I get expected results with class but when I do `$('#@Html.IdFor(m => Model.AmountOptionList)').focus();` It does not work. Any ideas?